# Post-conversion ketubah

Tags: minhag, conversion-to-judaism, wedding, ketubah

She's Jewish. He wasn't. 2+ decades later, he converted. (I don't know when he first intended to... these are the parents of co-workers of a friend of mine.)

Can they get a ketubah now? Should they?

Comment: They need more then a ketubah - they need to get married first. Was this an orthodox conversion? Because usually the Rabbi will require that they separate for a period of time first, then convert, then get married and re-join.

Comment: Note that answers on this site aren't intended to be put into practice without consultation of a rabbi: See FAQ http://judaism.stackexchange.com/faq#notes

Answer (score 6):

It is prohibited for a man to live with his wife without *ketubah*. This is so even when there had been one that was lost or destroyed, such a situation  requires another *ketubah* to be prepared prior to continuing to live together as man and wife (Shulchan Aruch, Even HaEzer 66:3). That a couple had been together without a *Ketubah* does not obviate the need, much less preclude the possibility, of one to be prepared for them.

It is difficult to imaging a situation where a non-Jewish spouse converted through a legitimate and competent *Beis Din* (or most illegitimate and incompetent ones as well) without this eventuality taken care of. Although I'm feel a bit silly speculating about a second/third hand story if the conversion has in fact already taken place, a Jewish wedding was likely preformed afterwards. If there is no known *ketubah* I would guess it was because they didn't realize the full significance of the document and misplaced and forgot about it. If this is the case it must be replaced as soon as possible.